# test class 4..System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: unit-test

```
public class fileAttach{
Public Attachment myfile{get;set;}
Public String VMfileName{get;set;}
public String ContactIds{get;set;}
public Contact con{get;set;}
public List<Contact> contacts{get;set;}
Public Attachment getmyfile()
    {
        myfile = new Attachment();
        return myfile;
    }

    public fileAttach(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       ContactIds= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('array');
      }
 Public Pagereference Savedoc()
    {
      if(ContactIds!= null || ContactIds!= ''){
         List<String> strConIds= ContactIds.split(',');
            for(Id conId:strConIds){
                Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId =conId,name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);
                insert a;
                 }
}
 return null;
 }   
}
```

test class...

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
public class testfileattach
{
    static testmethod void testfileattach()
    {
        Contact con=new Contact(LastName='Test Name',payroll__c='rakhul');
        insert con;
        Pagereference ref=page.conatactsaved;
        ref.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(con.id));//for page referenc
        Test.setcurrentpage(ref);
        ApexPages.StandardController cont = new ApexPages.StandardController(con);
        fileAttach fill=new fileAttach(cont);
        fill.VMfileName='';
        Attachment att=new Attachment();
        att=fill.getmyfile();
        fill.Savedoc();
    }
  }
```

test class passed with 50 %code coverage
    but whenever i was calling pagerefence  savedoc method getting error that

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>       stack trace
>       Class.fileAttach.Savedoc: line 24, column 1
>       Class.testfileattach.testfileattach: line 16, column 1

Comment: best practice - get rid of `seeAllData=true` - either now or in the future, you or your successor will come to regret this during a deployment. Mock all records as required in the testmethod/testclass. and don't forget asserts to verify that the code did what you expected

Answer (score 2):

In SaveDoc, you should be using &&, not ||. As it stands, your code should throw a NullPointerException.

That's the point of a unit test. To make sure that your code doesn't have any logic bugs. Your unit test actually exposed an error.

Comment: how to resolve that one sfdcfox

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary As I said, use && instead of ||. That'll fix your null pointer exception. You could also write it as `if(String.isNotBlank(ContactIds))`...

Comment: yeah succeed than you -sfdcfox

Comment: List<String> strConIds= ContactIds.split(',');
            for(string conId:strConIds){
                Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId =conId,name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);
                insert a;   ///these lines are not covering

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary Because your code is broken. Fix your 'if' statement, then fix your unit test. Your unit test must set ContactIds to a non-null value so it may be used properly. You may also want to increase your error protection against bugs like invalid Id's, etc. You have a bit of work to do before you let that code loose in production.

Comment: yeah i fixed the if statement